# Cannot implicitly convert type with interface

Tags: c#, list, interface, return, typeconverter

I am coding a C# Xamarin application, and am getting the following error:

```
Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SimpleMapDemo.AndroidMapLocationImageViewModel>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SimpleMapDemo.AndroidIGridViewItemWithAssets>'
```

I am getting the error at this line:

```
return androidMapLocationImageGalleryViewModel.images;
```

In the following function:

```
public List<AndroidIGridViewItemWithAssets> GetAndroidMapLocationItemGridViewItemsFromWebService(string type, int webServiceId)
{
    if (type.Equals("Image Gallery")) 
    {
        AndroidMapLocationImageGalleryViewModel androidMapLocationImageGalleryViewModel = GetAndroidMapLocationImageGallery (webServiceId);
        return androidMapLocationImageGalleryViewModel.images;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is my `AndroidMapLocationImageGalleryViewModel` code:

```
public class AndroidMapLocationImageGalleryViewModel
{
    public int mapLocationItemImageGalleryId { get; set; } //may not be needed
    public List<AndroidMapLocationImageViewModel> images;

    public AndroidMapLocationImageGalleryViewModel ()
    {
        images = new List<AndroidMapLocationImageViewModel> ();
    }   
}
```

The `AndroidMapLocationImageViewModel` inherits from `AndroidIGridViewItemWithAssets`.

Can I please have some help with this code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Classes are not covariant, only interfaces.

Comment: This is a duplicate, looking for a good candidate for reference now.

Comment: There can be other better duplicates, but a bit hard to find, too generic search words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need:

```
return androidMapLocationImageGalleryViewModel.images
    .Cast<AndroidIGridViewItemWithAssets>()
    .ToList();
```

Cast method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You need to add `.ToList()` after the cast, since `.Cast<T>()` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` instead of a list.